# How to get clients computer name using asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am supporting a system that needs to get the client's computer name I try different codes but all of them just get the computer name of the host server, not the client's computer name. Here's the snippet:

```
 public void CreateEvents(string className, string eventName, string eventData, string userId)
    {
        string hostName = Dns.GetHostName(); // Retrive the Name of HOST  
        string compname= HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
       

        var browser = HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser + " " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Version;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
        {
            userId = compname;
        }

        var entity = new EventLog
        {
            ClassName = className,
            EventName = eventName,
            EventData = eventData,
            IpAddress = ipAddress,
            Browser = browser,
            UserId = userId,
            CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
        };

        _db.EventLogs.Add(entity);
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public string GetIpAddress()
    {
       HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
        string compname=    context.Request.UserHostAddress; //System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
        return compname;
    }
```

Comment: Server and Client Browser are in same network?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No you can't**, unless the client sends such info when making HTTP requests. By "client", I'm referring to *any* - some app, browser, etc.

You can inspect your own browser request flow using standard browser dev tools and see *exactly* what info your browser is sending. It will not have your machine name (unless something in your machine is and that would likely be a problem).

That said, [HTTP Header data is what you have aside from standard *network info*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524602(v=vs.90)) such as IP address (which also isn't guaranteed to be the client's IP address - it could be the client's network address). The closest you can get to is `hostname` if it exists, and even then, just like IP address, is not guaranteed to be machine name.

A possible exception would be in an internal network (LAN).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in my case I want to get the clients computer name and save it into the database to be the ID of that machine rather than IP Address when login into the system. The user can't login to the system unless the machine/computer their using is authorized or registered to the system.

Comment: @Bot Unless you're in a controlled environment (LAN) - your network, all the clients are in your network, where you can control all your clients, as above, you **cannot**. You have to rethink your authorization scheme.

Comment: @Bot I second EdSF's stance, and add that the reason you cannot is because anything you can use to ID the client computer can be faked. The best you can do is authenticate the user themselves. Even when on a LAN your app wouldn't be able to authenticate the device directly using web protocols. It would depend on the domain controller reporting the expected computer name based on the IP the requests are coming from. So technically that's "out of band" for your app.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress
```

for getting the IP address, also `Request` has `UserHostName` but I am not sure about this property

Answer (score -2):

You can get computer name as follows:

```
Environment.MachineName.ToString()
```

You can get hosting server name as follows:

```
Server.MachineName.ToString()
```

Comment: Some hosting servers block these functions not to expose this information e.g. IBM Bluemix Servers.

Comment: I try this but what I get is the host serve computer name not the client.

Comment: That's not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: That's how is it working on my project exactly, as I said earlier, it depends on server.

Comment: Hosting server. It depends where it’s hosted.

Comment: It's there any way to solved this issues of mine? Were can I change the settings for me to be able to get the clients computer name? My hosting server is my computer only and I am using other pc to test my code if its working.

Comment: The OP is asking for **client**, not **server**